# R: pairwise extraction of common elements between multiple character lists

Tags: r

I have several lists with gene names like this:

List1:

```
XLOC_012482 
XLOC_019357 
XLOC_014642 
XLOC_010021 
XLOC_013282
```

List2:

```
XLOC_012482 
XLOC_019357 
XLOC_004860 
XLOC_004022 
XLOC_002278
```

List3:

```
XLOC_004860 
XLOC_004022 
XLOC_006292 
XLOC_006616 
XLOC_013802
```

And I want to extract the common elements between all pairs of lists. I tried using `intersect` but I could not use it on characters, and I also don't know how to perform this on all pairwise combinations.

Comment: `intersect` works on characters for me. You may be working with factor variables.

Comment: The above don't look like multiple lists. You seem to have several `character` vectors. If all those vectors are stored in a `list` object, you can try `combn(mylist,2,FUN=function(x) do.call(intersect,x),simplify=FALSE)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put your lists into a single list `li` and then use `combn` on the list with `intersect` as the function parameter:

```
combn(li, 2, function(x) intersect(x[[1]], x[[2]]), simplify = F)
# [[1]]
# [1] "XLOC_012482" "XLOC_019357"
# 
# [[2]]
# character(0)
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "XLOC_004860" "XLOC_004022"
```

*Data*:

```
li <- list(c("XLOC_012482", "XLOC_019357", "XLOC_014642", "XLOC_010021", 
"XLOC_013282"), c("XLOC_012482", "XLOC_019357", "XLOC_004860", 
"XLOC_004022", "XLOC_002278"), c("XLOC_004860", "XLOC_004022", 
"XLOC_006292", "XLOC_006616", "XLOC_013802"))
```

Comment: That's what I suggested in the comments. +1.

Comment: I combined my full lists into `mylist` and get the follwing error: `Error in combn(mylist, 2, function(x) intersect(x[[1]], x[[2]]), simplify = F) : 
  n < m`

Comment: Can you `dput` your data? i.e. paste the result of `dput(mylist)`?

Comment: Your `mylist` is one level deeper than it should be and they are factor variable which could potentially cause problem also. After this transformation `mylist <- mylist[[1]]; mylist <- lapply(mylist, as.character)` it should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This is also helpful using `table` (I use the same `li` list as @Psidom's answer):

```
tb <- table(unlist(li))
```

will give you each sequence along with its count among all lists:

```
# XLOC_002278 XLOC_004022 XLOC_004860 XLOC_006292 XLOC_006616 XLOC_010021 XLOC_012482 
#        1           2           2           1           1           1           2 
# XLOC_013282 XLOC_013802 XLOC_014642 XLOC_019357 
#          1           1           1           2
```

If you want to extract those duplicated:

```
tb[tb>1]

# XLOC_004022 XLOC_004860 XLOC_012482 XLOC_019357 
#          2           2           2           2
```